# SMTP email on Windows using C++

Tags: c++, windows, smtp

Is there any Windows Native API to send SMTP based message using C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a native API.  You will need a 3rd party component or to build this yourself.

Useful information in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example